# make access modifier one for all members in class

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

Have defined such class:

```
class Data
{
    internal string f_source;
    internal string f_output;
    internal string password;
}
```

As you see, I'm defining the access modifier for each member in it, explicitly.

Does exist some way to define the default access modifier for the all members in class at once?

Maybe, there is some attribute that makes such dream come true... Don't know...

I've tried to use the access modifier before the class declaration:

```
internal class Data
{
    string f_source;
    string f_output;
    string password;
}
```

But, no success!

Are the any suggestions: "how to fix such a problem?"

Comment: I don't see a problem here. This is C# not C++, and in C# you write the access modifier in front of every member, method, property and constructor. It makes it way clearer imho. Sometimes when i switch to C++ i wish i could use it there too, but again, thats C++ and not C#. (i know i could with 'public: int getValue()' );)

Comment: @Default the default of `internal` is incorrect. It defaults to the most restricted access modifier that's legal. That's `internal` for a class directly in a namespace but `private` for any member

Comment: @RuneFS ah. I read it to fast.. I removed my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design what your are asking for is not possible in C#.

The specifications of C# specifies which access modifier to use if none is given. The default is the most restricted access modifier that's legal. That is a type directly in a namespace (Ie not a nested type) is internal whereas any member is private unless otherwise specified.

This is, I'm sure, a design decision partly based on experience with how access modfiers in C++ works. a series of bugs can come from have specific sections of a file declaring `private`, `public`etc. It's a lot more expressive to have to state it (or know that if not specified it's as restricted as possible). Keeping the restricted as the default fits well with keeping as much as possible as internal (*) implementation details and only exposing what you really need to expose

(*) not the modifier

Answer (score 3):

Your second definition  type makes your class accessable only within same assembly just for that class. No way to make all class members as internal for all members.

Chek this: [msdn internal defination&example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Good Luck!